# almost sure convergence of sums of triangular arrays

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, stochastic-processes

A well known result (see for example Kallenberg Theorem 4.17) is that if $x_j$ are symmetric independent random variables, then the following are equivalent:

i)$\sum x_j<\infty$ almost surely;

ii)$\sum x_j^2<\infty$ almost surely;

iii)$\sum \mathbb{E}[x_j^2\wedge 1]<\infty$.

Does anyone know if there is a generalization of this result to triangular arrays? In particular I am looking for a result giving conditions on a triangular array of deterministic positive numbers $\{a_{n,j}, 1\leq j\leq n\}$ which secure the almost sure convergence of sums of the form $\sum_j^n a_{n,j}\xi_j^2$, where $\xi_j$ are standard normal.

Thanks for your time!